# Generate random numbers which do not repeat by using formulas

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula

I want to generate 4 random numbers between 0 and 20 which do not repeat among themselves. i.e. For each subsequent generated random number, it must exclude the value of any previously generated random numbers.

E.g.

The 2nd generated random number must not be equal to the 1st one, the 3rd one must not be equal to the 1st and 2nd ones, and finally the 4th one must not be equal to the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd ones.

How to achieve that using Excel formulas?

Answer (score 6):

Put this in A2:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($1:$21)-1)/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,(ROW($1:$21)-1))=0),RANDBETWEEN(1,22-ROW(1:1)))
```

And copy down four cells.

[image]

Comment: I find this fascinating. I can see that it doesn't duplicate any of the values, and it is consistent. I can drag this down to 20 cells, and it gives me all 20 numbers in a different sequence each time. If you don't mind explaining this, can you walk me through how this formula works, please? I feel like there is so much to learn/unpack here that I currently am not understanding...

Comment: @jeranon Aggregate allows the use of arrays. `ROW($1:$20)` creates an array of number from 1 to 20.  The `/(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,ROW($1:$20))=0)` is what causes the uniqueness.  If it already exists then it will cause a `#DIV/0` error which the AGGREGATE is told to ignore, with the second criterion of `6`.  So each time it is copied down it creates a smaller and smaller array of numbers that have not yet been used.  Then the RANDBETWEEN() is the `k` which tells the AGGREGATE which to return.  We need to lessen the range of this by one each time becuase the array is one less each row down.

Comment: So, to be sure I understand this, the original array doesn't output anything, it is a way of giving an original data-set of 20 unique variables. From there, each iteration of the array has one more variable removed from the array, and then one is chosen at random from that new - reduced - data-set.
Building a formula like this feels like a pretty big jump from the very linear formulas that I seem to work with. Are/were there resources that you found particularly helpful that I can go do some digging on my own? Thank you.

Comment: @jeranon You are correct.  as to were to learn, I have no recommends, I just learned by doing.

Comment: will the formula generate a **0**??